# Error when saving xlsx workbook with package openxlsx

Tags: r

I'm going through the vignette example in the openxlsx package in R Statistics, but I can't save the workbook and I can't figure out why. The code below is a modified example from the vignette, just to keep it simple.

```
setwd("c:/users/kenneth/documents/r/2014-04-29_openxlsx")
require(openxlsx)
require(ggplot2)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Motor Trend Car Road Tests", gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Iris")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "Conditional Formatting")
saveWorkbook(wb=wb, file="basics.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE) ## save to working directory
```

The error message I get is:

```
Warning message:
running command '"zip" -r1 "c:/users/kenneth/documents/r/2014-04-29_openxlsx/basics.xlsx" "[Content_Types].xml" "_rels" "docProps" "docProps/app.xml" "docProps/core.xml" "xl" "xl/_rels" "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels" "xl/charts" "xl/drawings" "xl/drawings/_rels" "xl/printerSettings" "xl/printerSettings/printerSettings1.bin" "xl/printerSettings/printerSettings2.bin" "xl/printerSettings/printerSettings3.bin" "xl/styles.xml" "xl/tables" "xl/tables/_rels" "xl/theme" "xl/theme/theme1.xml" "xl/workbook.xml" "xl/worksheets" "xl/worksheets/_rels" "xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels" "xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet2.xml.rels" "xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet3.xml.rels" "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" "xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml" "xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml" ' had status 127
```

This is my sessioninfo:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1 openxlsx_1.0.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2    
 [5] MASS_7.3-31      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
 [9] Rcpp_0.11.1      reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2   
[13] tools_3.1.0
```

I have updated to the most recent version of R, devtools and Rtools.

Comment: Excel is a pain in the [redacted] to deal with. I've had better luck with the `xlsx` and `XLConnect` packages.

Comment: what does `Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip")` says?

Comment: @Luca. It dosn't return empty but "zip".

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you for the suggestions. I think these libraries are great, but I have some large workbooks where the java versions eat all my memory. I haven't been able to get around this problem, which is why I'm interested in this package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue here is that R can not find the zip application that comes with Rtools.

You can check if the Rtools bin directory is in the system PATH from R with the command

```
shell("PATH")
```

The output should look something like this (depending on where you installed Rtools):

```
PATH=c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\... etc
```

If the Rtools\bin directory doesn't appear anywhere in the string add it in.

Instructions to edit system path can be found here:
http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml")

If this doesn't work email me and I'll help you out further (email is in the vignette)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I added the two paths for Rtools and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem as OP.  I added the following to my PATH variable: 
c:\RBuildTools\3.2\bin;C:\RBuildTools\3.2\gcc-4.6.3

After restarting computer, the output of shell("PATH") reflected the changes and I no longer got error messages about zipping workbook.